# Store images or folder path in database: how?

Tags: php, image, file, path, store

My plan is to write a few news articles each day to display on my website.
Each news article will contain a certain amount of pictures. There can be up to 50 images in an article.

At this moment my images get stored like this:

```
/images/2014/theme1/01.jpg
/images/2014/theme1/02.jpg

/images/2014/theme2/01.jpg
/images/2014/theme2/02.jpg
...
/images/2014/theme2/50.jpg
```

I'd like to know how I can store these images into my database. I already read a lot about this subject and heard that storing the folder path into the database is better than the images itself.

But how should I do this? The maximum amount of pictures per article is 50, so do I really have to create 50 columns (one for each possible image) or is there another way to do is?

Comment: just reconsider the table schema. If could be `id | article_id | img_url`

Comment: Read up on database normalisation. It should help you out with what you want to achieve. Have a table for the article and another table for the image paths.

Answer (score 0):

@Luca Prodan Flow this Link. [.Net core Add folder in static folder (www) and save image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197568/net-core-add-folder-in-static-folder-www-and-save-image-file) and store the: "PathWithFolderName + "/ImageName.png" in database.