# .Net core Add folder in static folder (www) and save image file

Tags: image, file, asp.net-core, directory, static-files

Add file in the static folder and save an image in the static folder.

Save base64 image in the Dot net core project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class EventMastersController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env; 

    public EventMastersController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public void AddFolderAndImage()
    {
        var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath;
        var PathWithFolderName = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, "MyFolder");


        if (!Directory.Exists(PathWithFolderName))
        {
            // Try to create the directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(PathWithFolderName);


            string Base64String = eventMaster.BannerImage.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);

            Image image;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }

            image.Save(PathWithFolderName + "/ImageName.png");
    }

}
```

Comment: can you give a example for PathWithFolderName

Comment: Refer to this: How to save IFormFile to disk?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322085/how-to-save-iformfile-to-disk/39322161