# System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core

I want to save an image to a project folder in my ASP.NET Core application after it was sent in Base64 format from Angular and converted, but an exception

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+

is thrown in the following statement:  `image.Save(Path,ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Here is my code:

```
string convert = request.Avatar.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", String.Empty);

byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(convert);
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
{
    string Path = @"Image\ddd.jpg";    
    image.Save(Path,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: try replace `image.Save(..)` with `using(var bitmap = new Bitmap(image)) {
bitmap .Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);}` also check that the folder have read/write permissions

Comment: i checked the permissions and it gives the same error

Comment: Is there another way to save an image in a folder?

Comment: not that im aware of, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197568/net-core-add-folder-in-static-folder-www-and-save-image-file) i know its very similar to your code but maybe it could help you